# Не убирается поле авторизации после самой авторизации

Tags: php

Сделал проверку на авторизацию, и, если пользователь авторизовался, то писать "Добро пожаловать, ***", "У вас .... игровых монет"(т.к., делаю игровой проект).Но после передачи данных методом POST, поля никуда не исчезают, а приветствие появляется сразу под блоком с полями.Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы получилось вместо блока авторизации, блок с приветствием и подобной информацией.Вот весь код:

`<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo
        '<left>
            <form method="post" action="index.php">

                <div class="form">
                    <center>
                    <li align="center">Вход</li>
                        <img src="img/user.png" width="20" height="20">
                    <div class="user">
                        <input type="text" name="e_login" required style="width:90px; border-radius:5px; vertical-align:middle;"><br>
                    </div>
                <div class="img1">
                        <img src="img/key.png">
                <div class="key">
                        <input type="password" name="e_password" required style="width:90px; border-radius:5px; vertical-align:middle;"><br>
                <div class="input">
                        <input type="submit" name="enter" value="OK" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                        <a href=""><li style="font-size: 15px;">Забыл пароль</li></a>
                </div>';
        }
    if(isset($_POST['e_login']) and isset($_POST['e_password'])){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $e_login;
        echo '<div style="width:150px; hieght:500px;margin-top:0px;padding:0px;">
                <left>
                    <li>Добро пожаловать,</li>'; echo $_SESSION['name']; //здесь такой стремный код, ибо иначе не выводит имя пользователя 
echo '
                </left>
                <center>
                    <li>Ваши данные</li>
                </center>
                <left>
                    <li>игровых монет:</li>
                    <li>алмазов:</li>
                </left>
                </div>';
    }
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо перенести проверку наличия POST параметров `if(isset($_POST['e_login'])...`  до проверки наличия переменной сессии `if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))`

Comment: я бы сказал что как то не правильно проверять есть ли переменные в post и сразу писать в session так можно под любым юзером логиниться.

Comment: Ну, у него нету так или иначе проверок на верность отправленных данных нигде.